# Leapfrog Integration with velocity-dependent force

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

favorite
In every reference I found on the internet, the ODEs to be solved are essentially

$$
\frac{dx}{dt}=v\\
\frac{dv}{dt}=F(t,x)
$$
I am currently working on a hydrodynamical simulation, and would like to know if it's possible and advantageous to use a function of velocity in the leapfrog scheme. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as I know, [Leapfrog integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leapfrog_integration) is designed for position-dependent (conservative) forces. For other types of problems, one can use [Runge-Kutta methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods), [BDFs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backward_differentiation_formula), and many other methods (cf. the book *Numerical Methods for Ordinary Differential Equations* by John Butcher).

Comment: So Leapfrogging or any other Verlet variant or variation thereof makes only sense if you have a conserved quantity and can show that it remains conserved to a higher error order in the numerical scheme.

Comment: @LutzLehmann so if $\dot v = F(v)$ does that mean you cannot use Leapfrog or Verlet?

Comment: You could still use the leapfrog scheme in the sense of my answer in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4191818/discretization-of-ode-system, but a straight application of the trapezoidal method would appear more natural here. The order is the same, and there is no structural advantage for either approach.