# Discretization of ODE system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, dynamical-systems, runge-kutta-methods

I am fairly new to the discretization of ODE systems (indeed a good reference would be helpful). I have a system of ODEs that basically looks like this
$$
\begin{align}
    \frac{d x(t)}{dt} &= v(t) \\
    \frac{d v(t)}{dt} &= a(t, x_t, v_t)
\end{align}
$$
How do I discretize this and , given a discretization, how do I know if it's correct? I have seen in an example online something like this:

$$
\begin{align}
    x_{t + \delta/2} &= x_t + \frac{\delta}{2} v_t \\
    v_{t + \delta/2} &= v_t + \frac{\delta}{2}a(t, x_{t + \delta/2}, v_t)\\
    x_{t + \delta }  &= x_{t + \delta/2} + \frac{\delta}{2} v_{t + \delta/2}
\end{align}
$$
Does it make sense? is this a correct discretization and why? what properties does it have?

Comment: I might be misremembering, but this looks like the leapfrog method. There are others like Verlet/velocity Verlet, Runge-Kutta methods, amongst many others.

Comment: The important property in equations of this type is that if the force is the gradient of something (which in 1 space dimension it always is) then the total energy, or perhaps some perturbation of it, should be conserved. This is important to get reasonable results on long time scales. There is a class of methods called *symplectic integrators* that have this property. If I recall correctly this method is symplectic.

Comment: No, that is an one-and-a-half steps of the basic explicit Euler method, but even then the second formula is inconsistent. With $$x_{t + \delta }  = x_{t} + \delta v_{t + \delta/2}$$ etc. you would get the second-order explicit midpoint method. // Check out the usual Runge-Kutta methods, symplectic methods only apply if the system is actually Hamiltonian. Other geometric-integration methods only apply if the system is invariant under some Lie-group action.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I think the problem under consideration is indeed Hamiltonian (I think!). Do you have any good reference to learn about all this?

Comment: Sorry, the case where it's Hamiltonian automatically is when $a$ depends only on $x$ and not $t$ or $v$.

Answer (score 2):

There is indeed a strategy in the approximation of second order DE or PDE like the wave equation that uses a dual or leapfrogged lattice. This is used to implement approximations of the derivatives stack as central difference quotients without spreading the support of the formulas too far
$$
\frac{y_{t+δ}-y_t}δ\approx y'_{t+δ/2},\\
\frac{y'_{t+δ/2}-y'_{t-δ/2}}δ\approx y''_t.
$$
If the formula for the right side does not satisfy the graduation of the leapfrogged scheme, as here for $y''=a(t,y,y')$, one can repair that like in the midpoint method
$$
y''_t\approx a\left(t,y_t,\frac{y'_{t+δ/2}+y'_{t-δ/2}}2\right)
$$
or as in the trapezoidal method
$$
y''_t\approx\frac{a(t,y_t,y'_{t+δ/2})+a(t,y_t,y'_{t-δ/2})}2
$$
The next challenge is that these will then turn out to give implicit formulas for $y'_{t+δ/2})$. These get usually solved iteratively. One can make the iteration count fixed to get an explicit method à la the explicit Heun method, or with a variable number of steps until the error in the implicit formula is sufficiently reduced to be lower than the truncation error of the method.

---

In general this scheme will give no further advantages over its being of second error order and its compact support. In the case where $My''=-\nabla V(y)$ is the equation of motion for the Hamiltonian/energy function $H(y,y')=\frac12y'^TMy'+V(y)$, that is, $a(t,y,y')=-M^{-1}∇V(y)$, this leapfrogged method gives a variant of the Verlet method. This is still a second order method in general, but the energy oscillates inside a band of width $O(δ^2)$, which stays invariant with order 4 or better. The phase of the solution however will usually have a second order error.